# How to sum multiple values from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new at android programming as well as `firebase`. first of all look at the picture

Details image

[image]

In there I want to get all the "cost" part in total(sum). I've created the reference like that

```
DatabaseReference databaseBazars=firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BazarList");
```

now what procedure I can follow to get sum and show it in list view or in a toast message).

I've done this to get all the data from that(BazarList) node . and it perfectly showing on the `listview`.

[image]

```
  databaseBazars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 bazarList.clear();
                 for( DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     Bazar bazar = ds.getValue(Bazar.class);
                     bazarList.add(bazar);
                 }
            BazarList adapter = new BazarList(Bazar_Data_Input.this,bazarList);
                listViewBazars.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

now, how can I get the sum part of the cost. anyone, please help me

here is the Bazar Class

```
public class Bazar {
    String bid;
    String date;
    String cost;
    String name;
    String item;

    public Bazar(){

    }

    public Bazar(String bid, String date, String cost, String name,String item) {
        this.bid = bid;
        this.date = date;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.name = name;
        this.item= item;
    }

    public String getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simply iterate over list and sum

Comment: please do me a favor. please give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
databaseBazars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        bazarList.clear();
        Integer total = 0;

        for( DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Bazar bazar = ds.getValue(Bazar.class);
            Integer cost = Integer.valueOf(bazar.getCost());
            total = total + cost;
            bazarList.add(bazar);
        }
        BazarList adapter = new BazarList(Bazar_Data_Input.this,bazarList);
        listViewBazars.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("TAG", total + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

The output will be: `59512`.

Comment: i inserted data in firebase as string format. now it's showing may be type casting problem

Comment: I saw that your score field is of type String and that's why i have used `Integer.valueOf(bazar.getCost())`. Do you have an error?

Comment: Log.d("TAG", total); this line showing required string found integer

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry, I forgot to cast `total` to String. Please see my updated answer. I have added: `total + ""`. Does it work now?

Comment: it's works. thank you. a little problem occured . i cannot use total in other fucntion. that mean i can not show the value by clicking another button or pop up something like that ?

Comment: thank, i can show that via toast . but why i can't show into dialogue.

Comment: You can, but only if you use `total` variable inside `onDataChange` method. But, this is basically another question that is no related to the initial one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, if you have another issue, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. So if you still think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you have `bazarList` with items from firebase then simply iterate over list and do sum

```
databaseBazars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 bazarList.clear();
                 for( DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     Bazar bazar = ds.getValue(Bazar.class);
                     bazarList.add(bazar);
                 }
            BazarList adapter = new BazarList(Bazar_Data_Input.this,bazarList);
                listViewBazars.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            double sum=getSum(); // at this moment your list have results so call getSum to get SUM


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

below is code which will do the trick

```
 private double getSum()
          {
            double sum;
            for( int i = 0; i < bazarList.size(); i++)
                {
                     sum += bazarList.get(i).getCost;  // Assuming Bazar class has getCost Method
                }
            return sum;
          }
```

Comment: where do i have to write this getSum() function? in addvalueevent listner or Bazar class?

Comment: @Rudro in the same class where your other code reside.

Comment: still not getting it. brother :(

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseBazars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        bazarList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Bazar bazar = ds.getValue(Bazar.class);
            bazarList.add(bazar);
        }

        // Iterate and add all costs to sum
        double sum = 0;
        for (Bazar b : bazarList) {
            sum += Double.parseDouble(b.getCost())
        }

        BazarList adapter = new BazarList(Bazar_Data_Input.this, bazarList);
        listViewBazars.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
});
```

Comment: sorry i can not got it. where  i do have to write this ?

Comment: well, now how can i see the total value ?

Comment: how and where you want to show that's completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (i in snapshot.children) {
                    val item = i.getValue(CartItem::class.java)
                    cartList!!.add(item!!)
                }

                var sum = 0.0
                for (itm: CartItem in cartList!!) {
                    sum += itm.itemPrice.toDouble()
                }
                total_value.text = sum.toString()


                //Initialise my adapter
                mRecyclerView.adapter = CartItemsAdapter(applicationContext, cartList!!)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please add some info so that people reading this answer in future can understand

Comment: And Joel also try to answer with that same programming language used in the question.

Comment: With out explanation, it's impossible to apply your answer to the question.