# Reading data from my firebase database to activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am a beginner in android studio. For weeks I have been stuck trying to read data from my database to my activity (Available Rides). Right now I am only transfering the data from one activiy to the other and puting it into text view.

In a previous activity I alreadt managed to save the data on the database.

Idealy I would like to have  table view showing 3 columns. The first one beeing  "Deprture" the next one "Arrival" and the third one "Time". Then in each line have each child.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me!

Thank you in advance!

**Available Rides Activity:**

```
public class AvailableRides extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_available_rides);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String messageTime = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String messageDep = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
    String messageArr = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView26);
    textView1.setText(messageTime);
    TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(messageDep);
    TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView3.setText(messageArr);
}
```

Firebase database

[image]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: I have tried doing that but cant make it work.. :((

Comment: in that case, you should show your work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the `Trips` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to display that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tripsRef = rootRef.child("Trips");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String arrival = ds.child("Arrival").getValue(String.class);
            String departure = ds.child("Departure").getValue(String.class);
            String time = ds.child("Time").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", arrival + " / " + departure  + " / " + time);
            list.add(time);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", time);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
tripsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
aaaaaa / abababa / 10:00
bbbb / bcbc / 10:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much! how do i get the data to display on the table now? just assigning log to the table view?

Comment: That's the simplest part. Create a list, add those values to the, create an adapter and then set the adapter to the desired view.

Comment: Thanks!! how do i create a List from those values ( for example a list of the string time)?

Comment: As in my updated answer. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Actually, dont i need to add a adapter too in order to display the data on the list view? i tried creating a adapter on right after creating the list. Is that the right way?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315793/how-to-sum-multiple-values-from-firebase/48316404#48316404).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a root and select it. Then Retrieve all your respective data in your snapshot within that root. Here is a sample code:

```
Firebase yourDataRef = mRootRef.child("data");
yourDataRef .addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String messageTime = snapm.child("0").getValue(String.class);
            String messageDep = snapm.child("1").getValue(String.class);
            String messageArr = snapm.child("2").getValue(String.class);
            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        throw firebaseError.toException();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here content1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.con);
    course = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.co);
    reset_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("course data").child("1");
    reset_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   try {
                       String couure_details = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                       String course_content =dataSnapshot.child("contant").getValue(String.class);
                       content1.setText(course_content);
                       course.setText(couure_details);
                   }catch (Exception e)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(userActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.